# How to Configure Teradata Database in Anypoint Studio Mule

Tags: mule, database-connection, teradata, anypoint-studio

How to Configure Teradata Database in Mule. The Settings using Generic Databse confiiguration..I have username,password and server name with me.. using these how can i connect succesfully. Ans also what is the connector to be used and what is Driver Class name.

Answer (score 0):

1st Download terajdbc4.jar and tdgsscconfig.jar(optional) and add to your project build path in referenced libraries. Then goto Database connector. Click Generic Database Connector. enter under Dtabase URL:

URL: jdbc:teradata://databaseServername/USER=username,PASSWORD=password DriverClass Name: com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver(click search button and add which comes in drop down list)

If you want to add any parameters in URL.. just add it by separating with comma(,)

Test the connection. It will be successful.

Answer (score 0):

1st Download terajdbc4.jar and tdgsscconfig.jar(optional) and add to your project build path in referenced libraries. Then goto Database connector. Click Generic Database Connector. enter under Dtabase URL:

URL: jdbc:teradata://databaseServername/USER=username,PASSWORD=password DriverClass Name: com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver(click search button and add which comes in drop down list)

If you want to add any parameters in URL.. just add it by separating with comma(,)

Test the connection. It will be successful.

Need more help please let me know your query

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to connect Teradata from `Generic Databse confiiguration` is as following:-

```
<db:generic-config name="Generic_Database_Configuration" url="jdbc:teradata://<your_Ip address of the db_host>/DBS_PORT=1025,DATABASE=<db_name>,USER=<user_Name>,PASSWORD=<password>,CHARSET=UTF8"  
 driverClassName="com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver" doc:name="Generic Database Configuration" />
```

Which is in the form of
 `jdbc:teradata://<your_Ip address of the db_host>/DBS_PORT=1025,DATABASE=<db_name>,USER=<user_Name>,PASSWORD=<password>,CHARSET=UTF8`

and yes **terajdbc4.jar** and **tdgsscconfig.jar** are required.
Also make sure you are able to connect the Teradata DB if it is hosted in VM so that it is accessible fro Mule application. That's it requires :)

Comment: url: jdbc:teradata://*********/DBS_PORT=1025,DATABASE=test,USER=******,PASSWORD=******,CHARSET=UTF8

Comment: [TeraJDBC 15.00.00.20] [Error 1277] [SQLState 08S01] Login timeout for Connection to 10.208.13.21 Thu Dec 07 19:03:44 IST 2017 socket orig=10.208.13.21 cid=fd63067 sess=0 java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(SocksSocketImpl.java:126)   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:459)

Comment: I am not able to connect teradata from mulesoft